# SystemError: null argument to internal routine

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, nuitka

Running a Nuitka-compiled application results in an error

```
SystemError: null argument to internal routine
```

And if compiled in PyInstaller it will run perfectly

```py
import os
os.environ["PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT"]=""
import sys
import pygame
import time
import ctypes

pygame.init()
info = pygame.display.Info()
window_size = (info.current_w, info.current_h)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN, pygame.NOFRAME, pygame.SWSURFACE)
pygame.display.set_caption("")

hwnd = pygame.display.get_wm_info()["window"]
ctypes.windll.user32.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x0003)
ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowLongW(hwnd, -20, ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowLongW(hwnd, -20) | 0x80)

font = pygame.font.SysFont('SimHei', 50)

color = (255, 255, 255)
alpha = 0

text_list = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3", "Text 4"]
current_text_index = 0

fade_in_time = 1
fade_out_time = 1
show_time = 5
start_time = time.time()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
game_running = True
num = 0

while True:
    if  text_list[current_text_index] == text_list[(len(text_list)-1)]:
        num += 1
        if num == FPS*(show_time-fade_in_time-fade_out_time):
            game_running = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pass

    current_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = current_time - start_time

    if elapsed_time >= show_time:
        current_text_index += 1
        if current_text_index >= len(text_list):
            current_text_index = 0
        start_time = time.time()

    if elapsed_time < fade_in_time:
        alpha = int(255 * (elapsed_time / fade_in_time))
    elif elapsed_time > (show_time - fade_out_time) and game_running == True:
        alpha = int(255 * ((show_time - elapsed_time) / fade_out_time))
    else:
        alpha = 255

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    text_surface = font.render(text_list[current_text_index], True, color)
    text_surface.set_alpha(alpha)
    screen.blit(text_surface, ((window_size[0]-text_surface.get_width())/2, (window_size[1]-text_surface.get_height())/2))

    if game_running:
        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick_busy_loop(FPS)
    else:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            break
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

I tried to run the following command
python -m nuitka --onefile --standalone --follow-imports --include-package=pygame,ctypes,os F:\encrypt\draw.py

## Environment

nuitka --version
1.5.1
Commercial: None
Python: 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Flavor: CPython Official
Executable: C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe
OS: Windows
Arch: x86_64
WindowsRelease: 10
Version C compiler: ~\AppData\Local\Nuitka\Nuitka\Cache\downloads\gcc\x86_64\11.3.0-14.0.3-10.0.0-msvcrt-r3\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe (gcc).

Comment: this code works fine.  what are you expecting or what is the error that you get ?

Comment: **python is not compiled** (it is interpreted), so what you have said does not make sense.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't look at it some time ago, I asked the developers of Nuitka and they said it was a bug and it has been fixed @D.L